# Why program return -1073740940 between last code and return?

Tags: c

I can't understand why program return -1073740940, I want it return 0 as I want, and I tried different versions for troubleshooting:

V1:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {

    int order;
    int *binary = malloc(1);
    binary[0] = 1;

    printf("order = ");
    scanf("%d", &order);

    for (int x = 0; order > 0; x += 1) {

        binary = realloc(binary, binary[0]+1);
        binary[0] += 1;

        binary[binary[0]-1] = order % 2;
        order /= 2;

    }

    for (int x = binary[0] - 1; x > 0; x -= 1) {

        printf("%d", binary[x]);

    }

    printf("\n");

    return 0;
}
```

V2:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {

    int order;
    int *binary = malloc(1);
    binary[0] = 1;

    printf("order = ");
    scanf("%d", &order);

    for (int x = 0; order > 0; x += 1) {

        binary = realloc(binary, binary[0]+1);
        binary[0] += 1;

        binary[binary[0]-1] = order % 2;
        order /= 2;

    }

    for (int x = binary[0] - 1; x > 0; x -= 1) {

        printf("%d", binary[x]);

    }

    printf("\n");

    printf("awa");

    return 0;
}
```

V3:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {

    int x = 0;
    char *password = malloc(1);
    password[0] = 1; 

    printf("Password:");
    while (1) { // scanf

        password = realloc(password, password[0]+1);
        password[0] += 1;

        char cha; scanf("%c",&cha);
        password[password[0]-1] = cha;

        if (cha == '\n') {

            password[password[0]-1] = '\0';

            break;
        }

    }

    int len = password[0] - 2;

    // printf("[%d]",len);
    
    if (len <= 7) {

        printf("Too short.");

    } else {

        printf("Long enough.");

    }

    printf("\n");

    return 0;
}
```

Both V1 and V2 returned -1073740940 as its errorlevel, **but "awa" in V2 is printed correctly**.

V3 is another program for making sure the environment I use is correct (MinGW-W64 as compiler, Visual Studio Code as editor), and as I expect, V3 returned 0.

So, I am confusing about why program return -1073740940 in "nothing"? (at least there are nothing in source code)

Comment: `int *binary = malloc(1);` only allocates one byte. Use `int *binary = malloc(sizeof(int));` or `int *binary = malloc(*binary);`

Comment: ... and you have the same problem with `realloc`.

Comment: code `-1073740940` is `STATUS_HEAP_CORRUPTION`, which is consistent with the other comments.

Comment: @RaymondChen remark explains the return value, which I interpreted as random data corruption. This explains the symtom without assuming also some stack corruption, so I retreat my previous assumption. ;)

Comment: Thanks! I resolved problem successfully using sizeof(), and now I know alloc memory using only interger is really a confusing behavior, thank you.